# Ask about sub view in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel

I'm want to ask about sub view in laravel blade the specific situation is as follows. 
[a view of pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIFui.png)

I want when click to component 1(2), The contents of the child blade file in @section('sub-view') will be rendered in the @yield('sub-view'). and this is the code of the parent blade file. 
[parent blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGzMr.png)

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="{{url('/projects/comp1')}}">Component 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{url('/projects/comp2')}}">Component 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        @yield('sub-view')
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And the code of child blade file. 
[child blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNJdj.png)

```
@section('sub-view')
<p>This is component 1</p>
@endsection
```

and my route file 
[Route file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqunK.png)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'projects'], function () {
    Route::get('', function () {
        return View::make('pages.project.projects');
    });
    Route::get('comp1', function () {
        return view('pages.project.comp1');
    });
    Route::get('comp2', function () {
        return view('pages.project.comp2');
    });
});
```

Can someone just help me solve this problem? 
Thank

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details inside your question, not as a link. Please refer the [ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add an

```
@extends('parent') // or whatever your parent view is called
```

to your child view file.

For more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#template-inheritance